# Scale position of circle but not radius

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \draw[help lines] (-3,-3) grid (3,3);
    \draw (-3,0)--(3,0) node[right] {$x$};
    \draw (0,-3)--(0,3) node[above] {$y$};
    \filldraw (0,1) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

The line `\filldraw (0,1) circle (2pt);` is my focus. I'm scaling the image so I want the position `(0,1)` to be scaled, but I don't want the radius `(2pt)` to be scaled. I want the radius to stay `(2pt)` as the image is scaled `(scale=2)`.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me as if you want to scale only the coordinate system but not the graphic itself. For this, I recommend setting the *x* and *y* vectors to `2cm`.

This means that a coordinate `(2,3)` will be interpreted as the coordinate `(2*2cm, 3*2cm)` = `(4cm, 6cm)`, while, with the default `x` and `y` options, `scale=2` will do `(2*2*1cm, 3*2*1cm)`.

As the initial setting for the `step` of a `grid` is `1cm` we also need to change this to `1` so that it is recognized in the TikZ’ coordinate system (and not the canvas as with all values with dimensions).

---

Another option would be to locally reset any transformation and only scale the coordinate but you will need to repeat any given transformations again:

```
\filldraw[reset cm] ([scale=2] 0,1) circle (2pt);
```

There is also the possibility to use a node here:

```
\node[inner sep=+0pt, minimum size=+1pt, draw, fill, shape=circle] at (0,1) {};
```

when `transform shape` is false.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2cm, y=2cm, step=1]
    \draw[help lines] (-3,-3) grid (3,3);
    \draw (-3,0)--(3,0) node[right] {$x$};
    \draw (0,-3)--(0,3) node[above] {$y$};
    \filldraw (0,1) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your ideas. They worked and they helped me learn a lot.

Comment: @David You’re welcome. If you use the solution of my answer or if it helped you otherwise, you might [accept the answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/16595). I also noticed that you don’t have one single accepted answer [on your question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16203/david?tab=questions). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: That means click the checkmark?

Comment: @David Exactly. :)